# Famous questions

Tags: discussion

I noticed this
[Famous MO Question](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/37/famous-question?userid=15019).
Its title is:
"[Difference between Principal Component Analysis(PCA) and Singular Value Decomposition(SVD)?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/64579/6094)."

It has zero votes, but is one of the most "famous" MO questions—nearly 4-yrs old.
Anyone want to conjecture how such a question became "famous"?
And whether the "famous" criteria are reasonable?

Comment: "Famous" means "10000 views by *anybody*" -- the vast majority of these views can be by people who have nothing to do with MathOverflow. Thus the quickest way to get a question "famous" in the sense of the badge is to post the link in some place where *LOTS* of people see it, and to use a text for the link which makes average people curious. Perhaps this has happened here.

Comment: "famous" could also mean "viral", as in the perfect billiards break posted some months ago.  I imagine the present question ranks high on certain web searches.

Comment: @StefanKohl: By *anybody*, or *anybody with an MO account*? (Which does not undermine your point...)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: I think anybody on the internet.

Comment: Google seems to like Stack Exchange, and that's a very good page title for capturing people with that sort of question.

Comment: The math.SE duplicate of this question has over 45,000 views by now. Compare and contrast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a famous question of climate science deniers. They want the "hockey stick" to be broken. Alas, math won't help them, for it has been independently reproduced by a multitude of methods relying on a multitude of data. It is the paradigmatic showcase of the late Homo S Sapiens being epistemologically challenged.